# transform 0 in ’a’, 1 in ’b’, 2 in ’c’ etc

Tags: ocaml

As I am new in OCaml and I didn't find resources, I need your help in the resolution of this function ! I want to generate a list of numbers with transforming int to char.

```
module Util =
sig
  (* transform 0 in ’a’, 1 in ’b’, 2 in ’c’ etc... *)
  val int_to_char : int -> char
  (*gen_random_list long max *)
  (* generate a list of positive numbers <= max *)
  (* the length of the list is long *)
  val gen_random_list : int -> int -> int list
end
```

Comment: you say you didn't find resources, but did you even try ocaml.org? If so, was something lacking?

Answer (score 0):

There are good resources for OCaml at http://ocaml.org

Here's a function that converts 1 to 'a' and 2 to 'b'. But I'd say you need a more careful specification, there are many questions unanswered by your three examples.

```
let ntoc x = Char.chr (x + Char.code 'a' - 1)
```

Read about the [Char](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Char.html) and [Random](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Random.html) modules in the OCaml manual.

Comment: Thank you ! You are right. But can you tell me how can I generate randomly a list of positive numbers ?

Comment: This looks like a school assignment. You should read about the Random module, then write your own code. If it doesn't work, show the code here and explain what's not working right. Nobody wins if SO does your homework for you :-)